# How to use the Filter tool

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a function that gets a value from one cell and uses it in a filter that I have in another sheet to filter only that value. How can I do this?

Comment: I cannot understand about `a filter that I have in another sheet`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I have a table in a sheet where I have a filter provided by the Filter tool in Google Sheets. I basically want to have a function to attribute the parameters to that filter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a function for this in the Class Filter

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter

However, there are potentially better ways to accomplish your objective. Personally, I would suggest using the QUERY() function. The 2ns parameter is a string representing the SELECT statement and can easily be built based on values in a sheet. Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
=query(Schedule!A:F, "SELECT B,D,E,F WHERE C='"&A1&"' AND E > date '"&TEXT(CurrentDate,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ORDER BY B, E",1)
```

CurrentDate is a named range in another sheet

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

- Assuming that the [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) is already created, retrieve it via [Sheet.getFilter()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getfilter).
- Retrieve the value from the cell you want to display (`VALUE`) and the data from the desired filter column (`FILTER_DATA`). Use [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows), [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) for that.
- Filter out all mentions of `VALUE` from `FILTER_DATA`. You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that.
- Create a [FilterCriteria](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria) with [SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newFilterCriteria()) and build it using [FilterCriteriaBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder). Since you only want to display rows with `VALUE`, you have to hide all the rest (since [setVisibleValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#setvisiblevaluesvalues) is currently [not supported](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159051708)). You can use [setHiddenValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder#setHiddenValues(String)) for that.

#### Code snippet:

```
function filterValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Source"); // Change
  const filterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filter"); // Change
  const a1Notation = "A1"; // Change
  const value = sourceSheet.getRange(a1Notation).getValue();
  const filter = filterSheet.getFilter();
  const columnIndex = 2; // Change
  const filterValues = filterSheet.getRange(2,columnIndex,filterSheet.getLastRow()-1)
                                  .getValues().flat();
  const hideValues = filterValues.filter(current => current !== value);
  const filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                                       .setHiddenValues(hideValues)
                                       .build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(columnIndex, filterCriteria);
}
```

#### Note:

- In the sample above, the column to use as criteria is `B`, so `columnIndex=2`. Also, the sheets are named `Source` and `Filter`, and the desired value is in `A1` of `Source`. Please change all these according to your preferences.